# PHP group objects of same type together in one go

Tags: php, loops, collections

I'm creating a page where Users can give names to IP addresses they use (reversed DNS). These addresses are configured on Router ports (interfaces) and have the same UserId configured on them to keep them apart. A Router port can have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. This is the function that creates a PortCollection where every port has on their turn a collection of IP address objects:

```
public function testfunction() {
    $this->portCollectionMapper->fetch($this->portCollection);

    foreach($this->portCollection as $port) {
        foreach(['v4', 'v6'] as $protocol) {
            $this->addressMapper->fetch($port, $protocol);
        }
    }   
}
```

This function populates the portCollection with Port instances. Then for each protocol, addressMapper fetches all addresses of $port.

var_dump($this->portCollection) will eventually be like this:

```
object(PortCollection)#12 (2) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  int(1000)
  ["ports":protected]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    object(Port)#28 (6) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      int(2280)         
      ["addresses":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        ["v4"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          object(IPv4Address)#40 (4) {
            ["id":protected]=>
            int(863)
            ["address":protected]=>
            string(13) "1.1.1.0"
            ["prefixLen":protected]=>
            int(31)
          }
        }
        ["v6"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          object(IPv6Address)#42 (5) {
            ["id":protected]=>
            int(478)
            ["address":protected]=>
            string(39) "fe80:bc07::"
            ["prefixLen":protected]=>
            int(64)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Port)#27 (6) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      int(2302)
      ["addresses":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["v6"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          object(IPv6Address)#39 (5) {
            ["id":protected]=>
            int(488)
            ["address":protected]=>
            string(39) "fe80:bc08::"
            ["prefixLen":protected]=>
            int(64)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

At first glance, this doesn't look all that bad. I get all IP address objects separated for each port. However, for the page I'm creating I want to have all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses apart. To do that I have to loop through everything again (which does look horrible):

```
$ipv4addresses = $ipv6addresses = [];

foreach($this->portCollection as $port) {
    foreach($port as $addresses) {
        foreach($addresses as $address) {
            if($address instanceof IPv4Address) {
                $ipv4addresses[] = $address;
            } else {
                $ipv6addresses[] = $address;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question therefore is: how can I just do this loop once, fetch the addresses and then have all IPv4 and IPv6 objects apart?

Comment: is it possible to query the database for addresses given a specific port? that way you could have an AddressCollection, assign a port, fetch through an AddressCollectionMapper, then loop & separate

Comment: Yes, that's possible. The problem is, however, that I need to get all port ID's first in order to get the addresses. So I think there is no way to loop through everything once. I probably have to put code that collects port information in a service class?